# Oracle: my DML for Index recreation puzzle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

#### Problem anamnesis:

In order to automate index recreation for a PVJOURNAL table in oracle I wrote a procedure in a package.
The table PVJOURNAL locates in PROVIEW schema. My SPACEMAN user has enough grants in that schema. Here below is a DDL of the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE spaceman.tmp_itcm4052 is

-- This proc rebuilds ALL indexes of a specific.
PROCEDURE         idx_rebuild;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE BODY spaceman.tmp_itcm4052 is

--  ===========================================================================
PROCEDURE         idx_rebuild as
-- This proc rebuilds ALL indexes of a specific table. Run by Job
  v_sql_str     VARCHAR2(200);
begin

 FOR rec in (
             select owner ||'.'|| index_name as IDX_NAME,
                    tablespace_name          as TblSpace
               from sys.all_indexes
              where upper(index_type) = 'NORMAL'
                and upper(table_owner) = 'PROVIEW'
                and upper(table_name) in ('PVJOURNAL')
             )
 LOOP
     v_sql_str := 'ALTER INDEX '||rec.IDX_NAME||' rebuild tablespace '
                    ||rec.TblSpace||' online';
     -- ALTER INDEX ... SHRINK SPACE COMPACT
     -- ALTER INDEX ... DEALLOCATE UNUSED SHRINK SPACE COMPACT
     dbms_output.put_line('v_sql_str = '||v_sql_str);
     execute immediate v_sql_str;
     commit;
 END LOOP;
 end idx_rebuild;

END tmp_ITCM4052;
/
```

#### Problem itself:

The problem is that a call of the procedure under my SPACEMAN user

```
begin
 spaceman.tmp_itcm4052.idx_rebuild;
end;
```

ends up with error

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges - [full view of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iELHa.png)

But the direct run of the line, produced by the procedure, saved into `v_sql_str` variable and visualized by this piece of the procedure:
`dbms_output.put_line('v_sql_str = '||v_sql_str);`, done under the same SPACEMAN user works like a magic. [proof that direct alter does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdW0B.png)

#### Questions:

What wrong have I done to the gods of pl/sql? Why the call to the procedure fails whilst the same command, execurted directly - is not?

**UPD**: Not only `GRANT INDEX ON PROVIEW.PVJOURNAL TO SPACEMAN;` didn't help. Moreover, for whatewer reason not yet kown to me, GRANT ALTER ANY INDEX to SPACEMAN; didn't help either. 
Had doublechecked it with

```
SELECT PRIVILEGE
  FROM sys.dba_sys_privs
 WHERE upper(grantee) = 'SPACEMAN'
UNION
SELECT PRIVILEGE 
  FROM dba_role_privs rp JOIN role_sys_privs rsp ON (rp.granted_role = rsp.role)
 WHERE upper(rp.grantee) = 'SPACEMAN'
 ORDER BY 1;
```

- the privilege `ALTER ANY INDEX` (as well as `ALTER ANY INDEXTYPE` ) is in the list.

**UPD 1**: as it turned out - the `ALTER ANY INDEX` privilege is not sufficient in this case. What did helped me is that [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809), kindly provided by @Wernfried Domscheit. REspect, man!

The procedure created as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE spaceman.tmp_itcm4052 authid CURRENT_USER is
```

works like a spell.

Comment: from which user, you are calling the procedure?

Comment: @Tejash - both procedure call and direct alter execution are done under **spaceman** user. Package **spaceman.tmp_itcm4052** is also in the spaceman's schema.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a PL/SQL block you have only privileges which are granted to the user **directly**. Privileges which are granted by ROLE (e.g. DBA) do not apply inside a PL/SQL block (except role `PUBLIC`).

Grant `CREATE ANY INDEX` directly to the user, then it should work.

The behavior described above is the default, it is called "definer's rights unit". You can change it by adding `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to your procedure/package. For more information see [Invoker's Rights and Definer's Rights (AUTHID Property)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809)

N.b. `COMMIT` is not required after a DDL statement. Oracle performs an implicit commit.

Comment: thank you for an answer. I'd like to know is it possible to grant **alter** right to a specific index, not to **any index** on schema?

Comment: Try `GRANT INDEX ON PROVIEW.PVJOURNAL TO SPACEMAN;` But I don't know if it allows to rebuild an existing Index or just create new ones. Also note, such indexes might be defined in schema SPACEMAN rather than schema PROVIEW.

Comment: @Wernifried Domischheit, not only ``GRANT INDEX ON PROVIEW.PVJOURNAL TO SPACEMAN;`` didn't help. Moreover, for whatewer reason, not yet kown to me, ``GRANT ALTER ANY INDEX to SPACEMAN;`` didn't help either.
Made an update to the main post re this ... I'm lost by now ... Studying the link [Invoker's Rights and Definer's Rights (AUTHID Property) ][1] , provided by you earlier...

[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809

Answer (score 1):

Different grants are used when you invoke direct SQL and when it is used in the procedure.

> Privileges granted through a role (such as DBA) **are not available** to
> **definer's rights** stored procedures which is the default.
>
> Only privileges that are granted **directly to the user** are available in a
> definer's rights stored procedure.

You must grant the `ALTER ANY INDEX` privileges directly to your user.

Cheers!!